# Not seeing messages on Facebook when abroad

Tags: facebook

I'm from England but I'm currently surfing the web in France on holiday. I checked my Facebook today and I had a message, but when I tried to read it the message isn't displayed. Even the messages mailbox doesn't show; there's only a blue line at the top of the page and blankness. The chat also seems to be stuck with the loading symbol.

Is there something wrong with my Facebook, or is it because I'm on a public domain in a foreign country?

It turns out that when I logged in from another computer in my camp-site, Facebook didn't like it and locked my account I've now left the camp-site and it say to recover my account I have to log in on the computer again (or so I assume) is there anyway I can reassure Facebook that it was me using my account and not someone else??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the problem: I had logged in on a computer on my campsite and, as it was unrecognized, Facebook thought I had been hacked and locked my account. I have managed to go through all of the necessary security measures and regain access